# error after installing Ubuntu in windows 8

Tags: installation

Hello, I am using Acer Aspire 5738. I have installed Ubuntu inside Windows 8 in different drive. While booting Ubuntu its showing error:

> 1. Unknown file system
> 2. Load the kernel first.

Please help to recover from this problem.Thank you for reading.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu have you installed? How exactly did you install it (dual boot, Wubi, etc.)? What is the *exact* error you see on your screen? Please *modify* your question to include more details. Keep in mind that we can't see your screen, so we completely rely on all information you provide in your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you've used wubi to install Ubuntu *inside* a Windows filesystem, that won't work properly with Windows 8 because it doesn't shut down properly. If you want to dual-boot Windows 8 and Ubuntu, you must perform a real Ubuntu install.

Don't use wubi with Windows 8. Actually; you might want to avoid it in all versions of Windows because there are some inherent risks.